# Analyzing a very large CSV file and I have a memory leak somewhere but I can't find it

Tags: java, file-io, memory-leaks, java-stream, inputstream

When I run the program using a smaller data file, it works just fine, but when I run it using a larger (~450,000 lines of data) file, it crashes, saying garbage collection has run out of memory. I know it's a lot of code and I'm grateful for any suggestions you might have. Thanks!

I'm pretty sure the error is in the FileReader22 class, but I've included the DataAnalysis class, as well. There are two other classes, one that constructs the Flight object (Strings that represent the different columns of data) and a Runner class that outputs the data into a .txt file, but I'm 99% sure those aren't the issue.

Not sure if I need to use a Stream instead of a Scanner (not even sure how to use a Stream, tbh...)

EDIT: Thought it might be wise to include the error code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.toString(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.toString(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.toMatchResult(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.hasNextLine(Unknown Source)
    at FileReader22.makeList(FileReader22.java:24)
    at FlightRunner22.main(FlightRunner22.java:13)
```

Class that reads the file and parses the data into objects:

```
public class FileReader22 {
    private ArrayList<Flights22> rawFlights = new ArrayList<Flights22>();

    private ArrayList<Flights22> filteredFlights = new ArrayList<Flights22>();

    private ArrayList<Flights22> cancelledFlights = new ArrayList<Flights22>();

    public FileReader22() throws IOException {
        filteredFlights = filterFlights(rawFlights);
        rawFlights = makeList();
        cancelledFlights = makeCancelledFlights(rawFlights);
    }
    public ArrayList<Flights22> makeList() throws IOException{

        ArrayList<Flights22> rawFlights = new ArrayList<Flights22>();//Flights that weren't cancelled
        File file = new File("INSERT FILENAME HERE");
        try {
            Scanner fileFinder = new Scanner(file);//Reads csv file

            while(fileFinder.hasNextLine()){
                String line = fileFinder.nextLine();


                String[] columnData = line.split(",");
                if(columnData[19].equals("0")) {
                    String dayOfMonth = (columnData[0]);
                    //String dayOfWeek = (columnData[1]);
                    //String flightDate = columnData[2];
                    String carrier = columnData[3];
                    String tailNum = columnData[4];
                    String originCode = (columnData[5]);
                    //String origin3L = columnData[6];
                    //String originState = columnData[7];
                    String destCode = (columnData[8]);
                    //String dest3L = columnData[9];
                    //String destState = columnData[10];
                    String depTime = (columnData[11]);
                    String depDelay = (columnData[12]);
                    //String wheelsOff = (columnData[13]);
                    //String wheelsOn = (columnData[14]);
                    String arrTime = (columnData[15]);
                    String arrDelay = (columnData[16]);
                    String cancel = (columnData[17]);
                    String cancelCode = columnData[18];
                    String diverted = (columnData[19]);
                    String airTime = (columnData[20]);
                    String distance = (columnData[21]);

                    Flights22 flight = new Flights22(dayOfMonth, carrier, 
                            tailNum, originCode, destCode,
                            depTime, depDelay, arrTime, 
                            arrDelay, cancel, cancelCode, diverted, airTime, 
                            distance);
                    rawFlights.add(flight);
                }
            }
            fileFinder.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
       filterFlights(rawFlights);
       makeCancelledFlights(rawFlights);
       return this.rawFlights;
        }

    public boolean isFullFilled(Flights22 flight) {

        if(flight.getAirTime().equals(null) ||
                flight.getArrDelay().equals("") ||
                //flight.getArrTime().equals("") || 
                flight.getCancel().equals("") ||
                flight.getCarrier().equals("") ||
                flight.getDayOfMonth().equals("") ||
                //flight.getDayOfWeek().equals("") ||
                flight.getDepDelay().equals("") ||
                //flight.getDepTime().equals("") ||
                //flight.getDest3L().equals("") ||
                flight.getDestCode().equals("") ||
                //flight.getDestState().equals("")||
                flight.getDistance().equals("") ||
                flight.getDiverted().equals("") ||
                //flight.getFlightDate().equals("") ||
                //flight.getOrigin3L().equals("") ||
                flight.getOriginCode().equals("") ||
                //flight.getOriginState().contentEquals("") ||
                flight.getTailNum().equals("")){
                //flight.getWheelsOff().equals("") ||
                //flight.getWheelsOn().equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true; 
    }
    public boolean isFinishedFlights(Flights22 flight){
        if(flight.getCancel().equals("0")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    }
    public ArrayList<Flights22> filterFlights(ArrayList<Flights22> flights){
        for(Flights22 flight : flights) {
            if(isFinishedFlights(flight) && isFullFilled(flight)) {
                filteredFlights.add(flight);
            }
        }
        return filteredFlights;
    }
    public ArrayList<Flights22> makeCancelledFlights(ArrayList<Flights22> flightList){

        for(Flights22 flight : flightList) {
            if(flight.getCancel().equals("1")) {
                cancelledFlights.add(flight);
            }
        }
        return this.cancelledFlights;
    }
}
```

Class that performs all of the data analysis:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class DataAnalysis22 {
   public HashMap<String, Integer> makeCancellationCountHash(ArrayList<String> airports, ArrayList<Flights22> forgottenFlights){
    HashMap<String, Integer> cancellationCountHash = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

       for(String carrier : airports) {
           int tally = 0;
           for(Flights22 flight : forgottenFlights) {
               if(flight.getCarrier().equals(carrier)) {
                   tally++;
               }
           cancellationCountHash.put(carrier, tally);
           }
       }
       return cancellationCountHash;
   }
   //Returns the total number of cancelled flights for all airlines
   public HashMap<String, Integer> makeCompletedCountHash(ArrayList<String> airports, ArrayList<Flights22> fulfilledFlights){
    HashMap<String, Integer> completedCountHash = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

       for(String carrier : airports) {
           int tally = 0;
           for(Flights22 flight : fulfilledFlights) {
               if(flight.getCarrier().equals(carrier)) {
                   tally++;
               }
           completedCountHash.put(carrier, tally);
           }
       }
       return completedCountHash;
   }  
   /*
    * Take the value from cancount, divide it by the sum of cancount and comcount, put it in a new hashmap
    */
   public String makeCancellationPercentage(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights, ArrayList<Flights22> forgottenFlights) {
       HashMap<String, Integer> completedHash = makeCompletedCountHash(castOfCarriers(finishedFlights), finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> cancelledHash = makeCancellationCountHash(castOfCarriers(finishedFlights), forgottenFlights);
       HashMap<String, Double> percentageHash = new HashMap<String, Double>();

       for(String comCarrierCode : completedHash.keySet()) {
           for(String canCarrierCode : cancelledHash.keySet()) {
               if(comCarrierCode.equals(canCarrierCode)) {
                   Double percent = 0.0;
                   percentageHash.put(comCarrierCode, ((Double.valueOf(cancelledHash.get(canCarrierCode)) / 
                           (Double.valueOf((cancelledHash.get(canCarrierCode)) + completedHash.get(comCarrierCode))))));
               }
           }
       }
       String maxCancelCarrier = Collections.max(percentageHash.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();

       Double maxCancelPercent = percentageHash.get(maxCancelCarrier) * 100;

       String answer = maxCancelCarrier + "," + Double.toString(maxCancelPercent);
       completedHash = null;
       cancelledHash = null;
       percentageHash = null;
       return answer;
   }
   //Returns a list of all of the carriers
   public ArrayList<String> castOfCarriers(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights){
       ArrayList<String> carriers = new ArrayList<String>();

       for(Flights22 flight : finishedFlights) {

           if(!(carriers.contains(flight.getCarrier()))){

               carriers.add(flight.getCarrier());
       }
       }
       return carriers;
   }
   //Takes all the tailNums from the flight objects and inputs them into an ArrayList w/o duplicates
   public ArrayList<String> allTailNums(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights){

       ArrayList<String> tailNums = new ArrayList<String>();

       for(Flights22 flight : finishedFlights) {
           if(!(flight.getTailNum().equals("")) && !(tailNums.contains(flight.getTailNum()))) {
               tailNums.add(flight.getTailNum());
           }
       }
       return tailNums;

       /*
        * Make a hashmap that uses an arraylist of each individual tailnum as the keys. Then, a for loop goes through all
        * of the flight objects and searches for each tailnum. When it finds a tailnum, it gets the miles flown and adds
        * them to the value in the hashmap associated with the proper tailnum key.
        */  
   }
   //Answers Question (3)
   public String tailTally(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights) {
       HashMap<String, Integer> tailNumTallyHash = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
       ArrayList<Flights22> flight = finishedFlights;
       ArrayList<String> tailArray = allTailNums(finishedFlights);
       String maxTailNum= "";
       int tailNumSum = 0;

       for(String tail : tailArray) {
           tailNumSum = 0;
           for(Flights22 flyer : flight) {
               int miles = 0;
               if(tail.equals(flyer.getTailNum())) {
                   miles = Integer.parseInt(flyer.getDistance());
                   tailNumSum += miles;  
               }
               tailNumTallyHash.put(tail, tailNumSum);
           }
       }
       maxTailNum = Collections.max(tailNumTallyHash.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
       flight = null;
       tailArray = null;
       tailNumTallyHash = null;
       return maxTailNum;
   }
   //Question (2)
   //Returns the cancel code with the most entries.
   public String cancelCodeCount(ArrayList<Flights22> forgottenFlights) {
       int cancelCountA = 0;
       int cancelCountB = 0;
       int cancelCountC = 0;
       int cancelCountD = 0;

       String cancelCountKing = "";
    for(Flights22 flight : forgottenFlights) {
           if(flight.getCancelCode().contains("A")) {
               cancelCountA++;
           }
           else {
               if(flight.getCancelCode().contains("B")) {
                   cancelCountB++;
               }
               if(flight.getCancelCode().contains("C")) {
                   cancelCountC++;
               }
               if(flight.getCancelCode().contains("D")) {
                   cancelCountD++;
               }
           }
           if(cancelCountA > cancelCountB && cancelCountA > cancelCountC && cancelCountA > cancelCountD) {
               cancelCountKing = "A";
           }
           if(cancelCountB > cancelCountA && cancelCountB > cancelCountC && cancelCountB > cancelCountD) {
               cancelCountKing = "B";
           }
           if(cancelCountC > cancelCountA && cancelCountC > cancelCountB && cancelCountC > cancelCountD) {
               cancelCountKing = "C";
           }
           if(cancelCountD > cancelCountA && cancelCountD > cancelCountB && cancelCountD > cancelCountC) {
               cancelCountKing = "D";
           }
    }
    return cancelCountKing;

   }
      // Makes an array of all unique airport codes 
   public ArrayList<String> airportArray(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights){
       ArrayList<String> allAirports = new ArrayList<String>();
       for(Flights22 flight : finishedFlights) {
           if(!(allAirports.contains(flight.getOriginCode()))) {
               allAirports.add(flight.getOriginCode());
           }
       }
       return allAirports;
   }   
   //Answers Question (4)
   public String airportAccruer(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights) {
       ArrayList<String> allAirports = airportArray(finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> airportArrivalHash = makeAirportArrivalHash(allAirports, finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> airportDepartureHash = makeAirportDepartureHash(allAirports, finishedFlights);

       HashMap<String, Integer> totalMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(airportArrivalHash);
       for(String airportCode : airportDepartureHash.keySet()) {
           if(totalMap.containsKey(airportCode)) {
               if(totalMap.containsKey(airportCode)) {
                   totalMap.put(airportCode, airportDepartureHash.get(airportCode) + totalMap.get(airportCode));
           }else {
               totalMap.put(airportCode,  airportDepartureHash.get(airportCode));
           }
           }
       }
       String maxNum = Collections.max(totalMap.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
       airportArrivalHash = null;
       airportDepartureHash = null;
       return maxNum;
   }
   //Method to make a hashmap of arrivals from each airport with airport code as key and tally of arrivals as value

   public HashMap<String, Integer> makeAirportArrivalHash(ArrayList<String> airports, ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights){
       HashMap<String, Integer> airportArrivalHash = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

       for(String airportCode : airports) {
           int tally = 0;
           for(Flights22 flight : finishedFlights) {
               if(flight.getDestCode().equals(airportCode)) {
                   tally++;
               }
           airportArrivalHash.put(airportCode, tally);
           }
       }
       return airportArrivalHash;
   }
   //Method to make a hashmap of departures from each airport with airport code as key and tally of departures as value
   public HashMap<String, Integer> makeAirportDepartureHash(ArrayList<String> airports, ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights){
       HashMap<String, Integer> airportDepartureHash = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
       for(String airportCode : airports) {
           int tally = 0;
           for(Flights22 flight : finishedFlights) {
               if(flight.getOriginCode().equals(airportCode)) {
                tally++;   
               }
           airportDepartureHash.put(airportCode, tally);
           }
   }
       return airportDepartureHash;
   }
   public HashMap<String, Integer> maxMover(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights) {
       ArrayList<String> airportList = airportArray(finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> airportArrs = makeAirportArrivalHash(airportList, finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> airportDeps = makeAirportDepartureHash(airportList, finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> maxMoverAirports = new HashMap<>(airportArrs);

       airportDeps.forEach((key, value) -> maxMoverAirports.merge(key, value, (v1, v2) -> (v1 + v2)));
       airportArrs = null;
       airportDeps = null;

       return maxMoverAirports;
   }
   //Answers Question (4)
   public String busiestAirport(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights) {
       HashMap<String, Integer> busiestAirport = maxMover(finishedFlights);
       String maxNum = Collections.max(busiestAirport.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
       busiestAirport = null;
       return maxNum;
   }
   //Answers Question(5)
   //Departures - arrivals
   public String biggestSource(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights) {
       ArrayList<String> airportList = airportArray(finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> airportArrs = makeAirportArrivalHash(airportList, finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> airportDeps = makeAirportDepartureHash(airportList, finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> busiestHash = new HashMap<>();

       for(String airportCode : airportList) {
           int sourceDiff = airportDeps.get(airportCode) - airportArrs.get(airportCode);
           busiestHash.put(airportCode, sourceDiff);
       }
           airportList = null;
       String maxSource = Collections.max(busiestHash.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
       return maxSource;
   }
   //Answers Question(6)
   public String biggestSink(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights) {
       ArrayList<String> airportList = airportArray(finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> airportArrs = makeAirportArrivalHash(airportList, finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> airportDeps = makeAirportDepartureHash(airportList, finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> sinkHash = new HashMap<>();

       for(String airportCode : airportList) {
           int sinkDiff = airportArrs.get(airportCode) - airportDeps.get(airportCode);
           sinkHash.put(airportCode, sinkDiff);
       }
       airportList = null;

       String maxSource = Collections.max(sinkHash.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
       return maxSource;
   }
   /*
    * If flight depdelay >= 60 tally++, if flight arrdelay >= 60 tally++, if flight
    * depdelay and flight arrdelay >= 60, tally -1
    */

   //Answers Question (7)
   public int AADelay(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights) {
       int AADelayTally = 0;
       for(Flights22 flight : finishedFlights) {
           if(flight.getCarrier().equals("AA")) {
               if(Integer.parseInt(flight.getDepDelay()) >= 60 || Integer.parseInt(flight.getArrDelay()) >= 60) {
                   AADelayTally++;{
                   if(Integer.parseInt(flight.getArrDelay()) >= 60 && Integer.parseInt(flight.getDepDelay()) >= 60) {
                       AADelayTally--;
                   }
               }
           }
       } 
   }
       return AADelayTally;  
   }
   /*
    * Take in the arraylist of fulfilled flights. Iterate through flights, finding biggest difference between depdelay
    * and arrdelay. If it is the biggest so far, store the day of month, the tailnum, and the depdelay in 3 different
    * variables. Return all three as a String. 
    */
   //Answers Question (8)
   public String savesTheDelay(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights) {
       String saveReturn = "";
       int maxSave = 0;
       for(Flights22 flight : finishedFlights) {

           int save = Integer.parseInt(flight.getDepDelay());
           if(Integer.parseInt(flight.getArrDelay()) <= 0 && save > maxSave) {
               maxSave = save;
               int moDay = Integer.parseInt(flight.getDayOfMonth());
               int saveDelay = Integer.parseInt(flight.getDepDelay());
               String saveTail = flight.getTailNum();
               saveReturn = Integer.toString(moDay) + "," + Integer.toString(saveDelay) + "," + saveTail;
           }
       }
       return saveReturn;
   } 
   //Answers Question (9)
   //Which airport had the fewest total flights?
   public String fewestFlights(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights) {
       HashMap<String, Integer> slowestAirport = maxMover(finishedFlights);
       String minNum = Collections.min(slowestAirport.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
       slowestAirport = null;
       return minNum;
   }
   public HashMap<String, Integer> mminMover(ArrayList<Flights22> finishedFlights) {
       ArrayList<String> airportList = airportArray(finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> airportArrs = makeAirportArrivalHash(airportList, finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> airportDeps = makeAirportDepartureHash(airportList, finishedFlights);
       HashMap<String, Integer> minMoverAirports = new HashMap<>(airportArrs);

       airportDeps.forEach((key, value) -> minMoverAirports.merge(key, value, (v1, v2) -> (v1 + v2)));
       airportArrs = null;
       airportDeps = null;
       return minMoverAirports;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Among other things, note that Jackson has a CSV mapper module that's cleaner to work with. Additionally, your `equals(null)` will throw NPE if true; use `== null`. It's simpler to say `isEmpty()` instead of `equals("")`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Attempting to call `equals` on a null will throw NPE; this is the reasoning behind why some people do `"literal".equals(variable)` instead.

Comment: my bad, sorry. @chrylis-onstrike-

Comment: Thank you! I replaced all the nulls, but I'm still getting the same error on the large file but nothing in the smaller file. Am I overloading the GC somewhere that I'm not seeing?